# Sorting a csv in Python - splitting first column with string delimiter then ordering via the second element then first element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Say I have a csv such as:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
bitter-banana,yellow,1,10
tasty-banana,green,1,7
bad-banana,yellow,2,11
tasty-apple,green,10,5
bad-apple,red,9,4
bitter-apple,green,1,7
```

How could I sort the the csv on the first column only whereby the part of the string that comes after the `-` delimiter is ordered alphabetically first. Then those strings that are identical after the `-` are sub ordered in groups alphabetically for the string before the `-` delimiter.

Output would be:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
bad-apple,red,9,4
bitter-apple,green,1,7
tasty-apple,green,10,5
bad-banana,yellow,2,11
bitter-banana,yellow,1,10
tasty-banana,green,1,7
```

I could use Pandas `sort_values` for the first sorting requirement such as:

`df = df.sort_values(by=["Field1"], key=lambda x: x.str.split("-").str[1], ascending=True)`

But I am not sure how how to tackle the second requirement of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split and expand the `Field1` into two columns then sort the dataframe using those columns

```
df.loc[df['Field1'].str.split('-', expand=True).sort_values([1, 0]).index]
```

---

```
          Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
4      bad-apple     red       9       4
5   bitter-apple   green       1       7
3    tasty-apple   green      10       5
2     bad-banana  yellow       2      11
0  bitter-banana  yellow       1      10
1   tasty-banana   green       1       7
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, split, reverse elements, join, and sort on that key:

```
df.sort_values('Field1', key=lambda x: x.str.split('-').str[::-1].str.join('-'))
```

Output:

```
          Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
4      bad-apple     red       9       4
5   bitter-apple   green       1       7
3    tasty-apple   green      10       5
2     bad-banana  yellow       2      11
0  bitter-banana  yellow       1      10
1   tasty-banana   green       1       7
```

Note: strangely enough, this appears to slightly more performant that split and sort_values:

```
%timeit df.sort_values('Field1', key=lambda x: x.str.split('-').str[::-1].str.join('-'))
```

> 771 µs ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
> each)

```
%timeit df.loc[df['Field1'].str.split('-', expand=True).sort_values([1, 0]).index]
```

> 1.39 ms ± 24.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

You'll have to test on real data or much larger datasets to see which performs better.

Comment: Nice reverse join trick :-)

Comment: Thanks, neat way to do it! Interesting to see the difference in performance there!